# Recreated Microsoft's Console Registry Tool's query functionality in C++ (REG.exe)

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, windows, winapi

I decided to try and recreate Microsoft's REG.exe query functionality."Reg.exe" is Microsoft's Console Registry Tool.

I used Microsoft's documentation of "[reg query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query)" to recreate it's functionality within C++.

I thought that it would be a great way to test myself and help to get a better grasp of Microsoft API's as well as better my programming skills.

I know it is not the best code. But if you could please provide constructive criticism as well as explain what you would do differently.

**Main.cpp**

```
/*
     Main.cpp
*/
#include <iostream>
#include "AquireInput.h"
#include "Error.h"
#include "Help.h"
#include "RegAdd.h"
#include "RegQuery.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    RegBlock aVal;
    int result = getInput(argc, argv, aVal);

    switch (result) 
    {
        case REG_ADD:           add(aVal);    break;
        case REG_QUERY:         query(aVal);  break;
        case REG_DELETE:                      break;
        case REG_HELP_GENERAL: 
        case REG_HELP_ADD: 
        case REG_HELP_QUERY: 
        case REG_HELP_DELETE: help(result); break;
        default: error(result); break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**AquireInput.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Error.h"
#include <map>

// Switch macro's
#define REG_ADD (1)
#define REG_QUERY (2)
#define REG_DELETE (3)

struct RegBlock
{
    std::wstring lHkey = L"";
    std::wstring lHkeyPath = L"";
    std::wstring lValueName = L"";
    std::wstring lDataType = L"";
    std::wstring lData = L"";
    bool lViewed[12] = { false };
    std::map<std::string, bool> lOptions = {
        { "/k",false },
        { "/d",false },
        { "/s",false },
        { "/c",false },
        { "/e",false },
        { "/z",false },
        { "/f",false }
    };
};

int getInput(int argc, wchar_t* argv[], RegBlock& aVal);
```

**AquireInput.cpp**

```
/*
     AquireInput.cpp
*/
#include <queue>
#include "AquireInput.h"
#include "Help.h"

// Parameter handles
#define V (0)
#define VE (1)
#define T (2)
#define D (3)
#define F (4)
#define S (5)
#define K (6)
#define C (7)
#define E (8)
#define Z (9)
#define VA (10)

uint8_t checkIdentifer(std::wstring &arg, bool viewed[])
{
    if (arg == L"/v" && !viewed[V]) 
    {
      viewed[VE] = true;    //  Deactivate value empty arg
      return V;
    }
    if (arg == L"/ve" && !viewed[VE]) 
    {
        viewed[V] = true;   //  Deactivate value specify arg
        return VE;
    }

    if (arg == L"/k" && !viewed[K])
    {
        viewed[D] = true;     //  Deactivate data search arg
        return K;
    } 
    if (arg == L"/d" && !viewed[D])
    {
        viewed[K] = true;    //  Deactivate key value search arg
        return D;
    }

    if (arg == L"/t" && !viewed[T]) return T;
    if (arg == L"/f" && !viewed[F]) return F;
    if (arg == L"/s" && !viewed[S]) return S;
    if (arg == L"/c" && !viewed[C]) return C;
    if (arg == L"/e" && !viewed[E]) return E;
    if (arg == L"/z" && !viewed[Z]) return Z;

    return L'x';
}

bool validDataType(std::wstring &aDataType)
{
    if (getDataTypeMacro(aDataType) != NULL) return true;
    return false;
}

bool validKeyName(std::wstring s)
{
    // Test if a minimum string length has been met
    if (s.size() < 3) return false;

    if (s.size() == 3)
    {
        if (s.substr(0, 3) == L"HKU")  return true;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wstring lHkey = s.substr(0, 4);
        if (lHkey == L"HKCR") return true;
        if (lHkey == L"HKCC") return true;
        if (lHkey == L"HKCU") return true;
        if (lHkey == L"HKLM") return true;
        if (lHkey.substr(0, 3) == L"HKU")  return true;

        return false;
    }
}

bool setHKey(std::wstring &s, RegBlock &aVal)
{
    // Test if a minimum string length has been met
    if (s.size() < 3) return false;

    // Addresses case in which user only input 'ADD HKU'
    if (s.size() == 3)
    {
        if (s.substr(0, 3) == L"HKU")
        {
            aVal.lHkey = L"HKU";
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 

        std::wstring lHkey = s.substr(0, 4);

        // Test if a lHkeyPath has been inputted
        if (s.size() > 4)
        {
            aVal.lHkeyPath = s.substr(5);
        }

        if (lHkey == L"HKCR") aVal.lHkey = L"HKCR";
        if (lHkey == L"HKCC") aVal.lHkey = L"HKCC";
        if (lHkey == L"HKCU") aVal.lHkey = L"HKCU";
        if (lHkey == L"HKLM") aVal.lHkey = L"HKLM";
        if (lHkey.substr(0, 3) == L"HKU") 
        {
            aVal.lHkey = L"HKU";
            if (s.size() > 4)
            {
                aVal.lHkeyPath = s.substr(4);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

int getInput(int argc, wchar_t* argv[], RegBlock& aVal)
{
    std::queue<std::wstring> lQueue;
    // Add argv values to lQueue 
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        lQueue.push(argv[i]);
    }

    if (lQueue.empty()) return MISSING_CORE_PARAMETER;

    // Get action (ADD,DELETE,QUERY..ect);
    std::wstring lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();
    lQueue.pop();

    // Guard against repeat parameter/sytax e.g /v Hello /ve /f /f  
    bool lViewed[12] = { false };

    if (lCurrentVal == L"ADD")
    {
        if (lQueue.empty()) return MISSING_CORE_PARAMETER;

        lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();

        // Check if ADD HELP was requested
        if (lCurrentVal == L"/?") return REG_HELP_ADD;

        // Check & Set HKEY value
        if (!validKeyName(lCurrentVal)) return NON_VALID_HKEY;
        setHKey(lCurrentVal, aVal);
        lQueue.pop();

        // Check validity of parameter
        while (lQueue.size())
        {
            lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();
            lQueue.pop();

            switch (checkIdentifer(lCurrentVal, lViewed))
            {
                case V:  lViewed[V] = true;
                         aVal.lValueName = lQueue.front();
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case VE: lViewed[VE] = true;
                         break;
                case T:  lViewed[T] = true;
                         lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();
                         if (!validDataType(lCurrentVal)) return NON_VALID_DATA_TYPE;
                         aVal.lDataType = lCurrentVal;
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case D:  lViewed[D] = true;
                         aVal.lData = lQueue.front();
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case F:  lViewed[F] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/f"] = true;
                         break;
                default: return UNKNOWN_PARAMETER;
            }

        }
        return REG_ADD;
    }

    if (lCurrentVal == L"QUERY")
    {
        if (lQueue.empty()) return MISSING_CORE_PARAMETER;

        lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();

        // Check if ADD HELP was requested
        if (lCurrentVal == L"/?") return REG_HELP_QUERY;

        // Check & Set HKEY value
        if (!validKeyName(lCurrentVal)) return NON_VALID_HKEY;
        setHKey(lCurrentVal, aVal);
        lQueue.pop();

        // Check validity of parameter
        while (lQueue.size())
        {
            lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();
            lQueue.pop();

            switch (checkIdentifer(lCurrentVal, lViewed))
            {
                case V:  lViewed[V] = true;
                         aVal.lValueName = lQueue.front();
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case VE: lViewed[VE] = true;
                         break;
                case S:  lViewed[S] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/s"] = true;
                         break;
                case F:  lViewed[F] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/f"] = true;
                         aVal.lData = lQueue.front();
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case K:  lViewed[K] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/k"] = true;
                         break;
                case D:  lViewed[D] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/d"] = true;
                         break;
                case C:  lViewed[C] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/c"] = true;
                         break;
                case E:  lViewed[E] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/e"] = true;
                         break;
                case T:  lViewed[T] = true;
                         lCurrentVal = lQueue.front();
                         if (!validDataType(lCurrentVal)) return NON_VALID_DATA_TYPE;
                         aVal.lDataType = lCurrentVal;
                         lQueue.pop();
                         break;
                case Z:  lViewed[Z] = true;
                         aVal.lOptions["/z"] = true;
                         break;
                default: return UNKNOWN_PARAMETER;
            }

        }

        // Make sure that search options are not enabled without first specifing a search criteria
        if (lViewed[K] || lViewed[D] || lViewed[C] || lViewed[E] || lViewed[T])
        {
            if (!lViewed[F]) return UNKNOWN_PARAMETER;
        }

        return REG_QUERY;
    }

    if (lCurrentVal == L"DELETE")
    {
        return REG_DELETE;
    }

    if (lCurrentVal == L"/?")
    {
        return REG_HELP_GENERAL;
    }
    return UNKNOWN_ACTION;
}
```

**RegQuery.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "AquireInput.h"

bool query(RegBlock &aVal);
```

**RegQuery.cpp**

```
/*
   RegQuery.cpp
*/
#include "RegQuery.h"
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include  <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 32786
#define MAX_DATA_VALUE 2000000  
std::wstring NULLWST = L"";  // Placeholder null value

inline unsigned hexValidInt(int aVal)
{
    if (aVal < 0)
    {
        aVal += 256;
        return aVal;
    }
    return aVal;
}

template <typename I> std::string n2hexstr(I w, size_t hex_len = 2) {
    static const char* digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string rc(hex_len, '0');
    for (size_t i = 0, j = (hex_len - 1) * 4; i < hex_len; ++i, j -= 4)
    {
        rc[i] = digits[(w >> j) & 0x0f];
    }
    // Corrects the order of the hex numbers e.g 34FE is corrected to FE34
    std::swap_ranges(std::begin(rc)+2, std::end(rc), std::begin(rc));
    return rc;
}

inline unsigned int convertData(DWORD &aRegType, DWORD &aDataLength, wchar_t *aData, std::wstring &aDataResult)
{
    std::wstring lDataResult;
    if (aRegType == REG_DWORD ||
        aRegType == REG_QWORD ||
        aRegType == REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN ||
        aRegType == REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN ||
        aRegType == REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN)
    {
        // Reverse loop 
        for (int i = (aDataLength * 0.5) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (aData[i] == 0) continue;
            lDataResult += convertToWstr(n2hexstr(hexValidInt(aData[i]),2));
        }
    }

    if (aRegType == REG_BINARY || aRegType == REG_NONE)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (aDataLength * 0.5); i++)
        {
            lDataResult += convertToWstr(n2hexstr(hexValidInt(aData[i]),4));
        }
    }

    if (aRegType == REG_SZ || aRegType == REG_MULTI_SZ)
    {
        int lEnd = (aDataLength * 0.5) - 1;

        // Avoid adding trailing zero
        if (aRegType == REG_MULTI_SZ)
        {
            lEnd = (aDataLength * 0.5) - 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lEnd; i++)
        {
            if (aData[i] == 0)
            {
             lDataResult += L"\\0";
             continue;
            }

            lDataResult += aData[i];
        }
    }

    aDataResult = lDataResult;
    return 0;
}

struct RegValue
{
    std::wstring lValueName;
    unsigned int lRegType;
    std::wstring lDataValue;

};

inline std::wstring constructKeyPath(std::wstring &aHkeyPath, std::wstring &aSubKey)
{
    std::wstring lSlash = L"\\";
    std::wstring lFullPath;

    if (aSubKey == L"")
    {
        lFullPath = aHkeyPath;
    }
    else
    {
        lFullPath = aHkeyPath + lSlash + aSubKey;
    }

    return lFullPath;
}

inline unsigned int getValueNameList(HKEY hKey, std::wstring &aHkeyPath, std::wstring &aSubKey, std::queue<std::wstring> &aValueList)
{
    std::wstring lFullPath = constructKeyPath(aHkeyPath, aSubKey);
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = lFullPath.c_str();

    int lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(
        hKey,
        lpSubKey,
        0,                      //add var
        KEY_QUERY_VALUE,        //add var
        &hKey
    );

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return lResult;
    }

    // Variables related to RegEnumValue
    LPDWORD               lpReserved = NULL;
    LPDWORD               lpType = NULL;
    LPBYTE                lpData = NULL;
    LPDWORD               lpcbData = NULL;
    DWORD                 dwIndex = 0;

    // Avoid adding lpValueName initial value 
    bool lSkip = true;

    while (lResult != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        wchar_t lpValueName[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
        DWORD   lpcchValueName = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

        // Add the list of value names to a vector list
        if (!lSkip)
        {
            aValueList.push(lpValueName);
        }
        else
        {
            lSkip = false;
        }

        lResult = RegEnumValue(
            hKey,
            dwIndex,
            lpValueName,
            &lpcchValueName,
            lpReserved,
            lpType,
            lpData,
            lpcbData
        );

        dwIndex++;

        // Return an error if lResult is not an acceptable error
        if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS && lResult != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
            return lResult;
        }
    }

    //Close key
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return lResult = 0;
}

inline unsigned int getSubKeyList(HKEY hKey, std::wstring &aHkeyPath, std::wstring &aSubKey, std::deque<std::wstring> &aSubKeyList)
{   
    std::wstring lFullPath = constructKeyPath(aHkeyPath, aSubKey);
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = lFullPath.c_str();

    DWORD i, lResult;
    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(
        hKey,
        lpSubKey,
        0,                       
        KEY_READ,         
        &hKey
    );

    TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
    TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys = 0;               // number of subkeys 
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 



    TCHAR  achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    // Get the class name and the value count. 
    lResult = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 


                                 // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.
    if (cSubKeys)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<cSubKeys; i++)
        {
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            lResult = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,
                achKey,
                &cbName,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &ftLastWriteTime);
            if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                // Attach parent key to child sub keys
                // e.g: key01/subkey01
                std::wstring lRelativePath = achKey;
                if (aSubKey != L"")
                {
                    lRelativePath = aSubKey + L"\\" + achKey;
                }

                aSubKeyList.push_back(lRelativePath);
            }
        }
    }

    //Close key
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return lResult;
}

inline unsigned int getValueData(HKEY aHkey, std::wstring &aHkeyPath, std::wstring &aSubKey, std::wstring &aValueName, RegValue &aValueData)
{
    std::wstring lFullPath = constructKeyPath(aHkeyPath, aSubKey);
    LPCTSTR lSubKey = lFullPath.c_str();
    LPCTSTR lValueName = aValueName.c_str();

    DWORD                      dwFlags = RRF_RT_ANY;        
    DWORD                      pdwType;                    
    wchar_t                   *pvData = new wchar_t[MAX_DATA_VALUE];
    DWORD                      pcbData = MAX_DATA_VALUE;

    int lResult = RegGetValue(
        aHkey,
        lSubKey,
        lValueName,
        dwFlags,
        &pdwType,
        pvData,
        &pcbData
    );

    // Check if lResult is okay
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        delete[] pvData;
        return lResult;
    }

    if (pcbData >= MAX_DATA_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Data Value Exceeded! Registery data value > 2MB!" << std::endl;
        return lResult;
    }

    // Convert data values & Store results
    std::wstring lDataValue;
    convertData(pdwType, pcbData, pvData, lDataValue);
    aValueData.lDataValue = lDataValue;
    aValueData.lValueName = lValueName;
    aValueData.lRegType = pdwType;

    delete[] pvData;
    return lResult;
}

/*
Show related functions
*/
inline std::wstring getHkeyStringName(HKEY aHkey)
{
    if (aHkey == HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) return L"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\";
    if (aHkey == HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG) return L"HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\\";
    if (aHkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) return L"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\";
    if (aHkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) return L"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\";
    if (aHkey == HKEY_USERS)  return L"HKEY_USERS\\";

    return L"NULL";
}

inline std::wstring getDataTypeStringName(unsigned int &aDataType)
{
    if (aDataType == REG_SZ) return L"REG_SZ";
    if (aDataType == REG_MULTI_SZ) return L"REG_MULTI_SZ";
    if (aDataType == REG_EXPAND_SZ) return L"REG_EXPAND_SZ";

    if (aDataType == REG_DWORD) return L"REG_DWORD";
    if (aDataType == REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN) return L"REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN";
    if (aDataType == REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN) return L"REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN";

    if (aDataType == REG_QWORD) return L"REG_QWORD";
    if (aDataType == REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN) return L"REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN";

    if (aDataType == REG_BINARY) return L"REG_BINARY";

    if (aDataType == REG_NONE) return L"REG_NONE";

    return L"NULL";
}

unsigned int WriteToConsole(std::wstring &aString)
{
    int lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    static HANDLE lConsoleAccess = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    lResult = WriteConsoleW(
                    lConsoleAccess,
                    aString.c_str(),
                    aString.size(),
                    NULL,
                    NULL
                );

    return lResult;
}

// Testing
//#define __nonEnglishMode
//#define __writeToDisk

#if defined (__writeToDisk)
std::wofstream file;
#endif

inline void show(HKEY aHkey, std::wstring &aHkeyPath, std::wstring &aSubKey, RegValue &aValueData, bool aDisplayPath, bool aDisplayValue, bool aLastItem)
{
    // Display Key Path HKEY/key/key..ect 
    if (aDisplayPath)
    {
        std::wstring lSlash = L"\\";
        std::wstring lFullPath;

        #if defined (__writeToDisk) 
        file << L"\n";
        #endif

        // Only attach subkey to path  name if it is supplied
        if (aSubKey == L"")
        {
            lFullPath = getHkeyStringName(aHkey) + aHkeyPath + L"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            lFullPath = getHkeyStringName(aHkey) + aHkeyPath + lSlash + aSubKey + L"\n";
        }

        //fwprintf(stdout, L"%s",lFullPath.c_str());
        WriteToConsole(lFullPath);
        #if defined (__writeToDisk) 
        file << lFullPath;
        #endif

    }

    if (aDisplayValue)
    {
        // Show registry value name
        std::wstring lValueName = (aValueData.lValueName);
        if (lValueName == TEXT("")) lValueName = TEXT("(Default)");

        // Show registry type
        std::wstring lDataType = getDataTypeStringName(aValueData.lRegType);
        std::wstring lDataValue;

        // Show registry data
        if (lDataType == L"REG_DWORD" ||
            lDataType == L"REG_QWORD" ||
            lDataType == L"REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN" ||
            lDataType == L"REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN" ||
            lDataType == L"REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN")
        {
            lDataValue = L"0x0" + (aValueData.lDataValue);
        }
        else
        {
            lDataValue = (aValueData.lDataValue);
        }

        std::wstring lKeyValue = L"    " + lValueName + L"    " + lDataType + L"    " + lDataValue + L"\n";
        //fwprintf(stdout,L"%s",lKeyValue.c_str());
        WriteToConsole(lKeyValue);
        #if defined (__writeToDisk) 
        file << lKeyValue;
        #endif
    }

    #if defined (__writeToDisk) 
    if (file.fail())
    {
        file.clear();
    }
    #endif
}

DWORD getDataTypeFilterMacro(std::string &aDataType)
{
    if (aDataType == "REG_SZ") return RRF_RT_REG_SZ;
    if (aDataType == "REG_MULTI_SZ") return RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ;
    if (aDataType == "REG_EXPAND_SZ") return RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ;

    if (aDataType == "REG_DWORD") return RRF_RT_DWORD;
    if (aDataType == "REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN") return RRF_RT_DWORD;
    if (aDataType == "REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN") return RRF_RT_DWORD;

    if (aDataType == "REG_QWORD") return RRF_RT_QWORD;
    if (aDataType == "REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN") return RRF_RT_QWORD;

    if (aDataType == "REG_BINARY") return RRF_RT_REG_BINARY;
    if (aDataType == "REG_NONE") return RRF_RT_REG_NONE;

    return RRF_RT_ANY;
}

bool isMatch(RegValue &aRegValueData, std::wstring &aDataType, std::wstring &aSearchItem, std::wstring &aKeyName, bool lCaseSensitive = false, bool lExactMatch = false, bool aSearchKeyOnly = false, bool aSearchDataOnly = false)
{   
    bool lResult = false;
    std::wstring lSearchItem = aSearchItem;
    std::wstring lValueName = aRegValueData.lValueName;
    std::wstring lDataValue = aRegValueData.lDataValue;
    std::wstring lKeyName = aKeyName;
    // Convert to lowercase
    if (!lCaseSensitive || !lExactMatch)
    {
        std::transform(lSearchItem.begin(), lSearchItem.end(), lSearchItem.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::transform(lValueName.begin(), lValueName.end(), lValueName.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::transform(lDataValue.begin(), lDataValue.end(), lDataValue.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::transform(lKeyName.begin(), lKeyName.end(), lKeyName.begin(), ::tolower);
    }

    // Search Key Names
    if (aSearchKeyOnly)
    {
        // Split and store the last key 
        // ...MyCo//Key1//Key3  ->> Key3
        auto const pos = lKeyName.find_last_of('\\');
        lKeyName = lKeyName.substr(pos + 1);

        if (lKeyName == lSearchItem)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Search Data 
    if (aSearchDataOnly)
    {
        if (lDataValue == lSearchItem)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Search both key name and data value
    if (!aSearchKeyOnly && !aSearchDataOnly)
    {
        if (lValueName == lSearchItem)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (lDataValue == lSearchItem)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

bool query(RegBlock &aVal)
{
    int lResult;

    #if defined (__writeToDisk)
    file.open("screen_output.txt", std::wofstream::app | std::wofstream::in);
    #endif

    // Variables related to Queries/Find
    HKEY                       hkey = getHkeyMacro(aVal.lHkey);
    std::wstring               lHkeyPath = aVal.lHkeyPath;
    bool                       lValueNameEmpty = aVal.lValueName.empty();
    bool                       lFind = aVal.lOptions["/f"];
    bool                       lSearchRecursive = aVal.lOptions["/s"];
    bool                       lFilterDataType = !(aVal.lDataType.empty());
    bool                       lCaseSensitive = aVal.lOptions["/c"];
    bool                       lExactMatch = aVal.lOptions["/e"];
    bool                       lSearchKeyOnly = aVal.lOptions["/k"];
    bool                       lSearchDataOnly = aVal.lOptions["/d"];

    // Specify the search value to use, either the key name or search param input 
    std::wstring lSearchItem = aVal.lData;
    if (!lValueNameEmpty)
    {
        lSearchItem = aVal.lValueName;
    }

    std::deque<std::wstring>  lSubKeyList;
    std::queue<std::wstring>  lValueList;

    // Get the list of value names if none is provided
    if (lValueNameEmpty)
    {
        lResult = getValueNameList(hkey, lHkeyPath, NULLWST, lValueList);

        if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            error(lResult);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::wstring  lValueName = aVal.lValueName;
        lValueList.push(lValueName);
    }

    // Get inital list of sub keys
    lResult = getSubKeyList(hkey, lHkeyPath, NULLWST, lSubKeyList);

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        error(lResult);
        return false;
    }

    RegValue lRegValueData;
    std::wstring lCurrentSubKey = NULLWST;
    std::wstring lCurrentValue = NULLWST;
    unsigned int lMatchTotal = 0;

    // Allows for the last subkey within the dequeue to be shown
    lSubKeyList.push_back(L"End");

    bool lDisplayPath = false;
    bool lDisplayValue = true;
    bool lNewLine = false;
    bool lMatch = false;

    while (lSubKeyList.size())
    {    
        // Search and Display keys when searching in KEY ONLY mode
        if (lSearchKeyOnly)
        {        
            lMatch = isMatch(
                lRegValueData,
                aVal.lDataType,
                lSearchItem,
                lCurrentSubKey,
                lCaseSensitive,
                lExactMatch,
                lSearchKeyOnly,
                lSearchDataOnly 
            );

            if (lMatch)
            {
                lDisplayPath = true;
                lDisplayValue = false;
                show(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lRegValueData, lDisplayPath, lDisplayValue, false);
                lDisplayPath = false;
                lDisplayValue = true;

                lNewLine = true;
                lMatchTotal++;
            }
        }

        // Display the key path in the case of empty key && list keys when not in recursive/search mode
        if (lValueList.size() == 0 && !(lFilterDataType || lFind) && lValueNameEmpty)
        {
            show(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lRegValueData, true, false, false);
        }
        else
        {
            lDisplayPath = true;
        }

        while (lValueList.size() && !lSearchKeyOnly)
        {
            lCurrentValue = lValueList.front();
            lValueList.pop();
            lResult = getValueData(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lCurrentValue, lRegValueData);

            if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                error(lResult);
                return false;
            }

            if (lFind || lFilterDataType)
            {
                lMatch = isMatch(
                    lRegValueData, 
                    aVal.lDataType, 
                    lSearchItem,
                    lCurrentSubKey, 
                    lCaseSensitive, 
                    lExactMatch, 
                    lSearchKeyOnly, 
                    lSearchDataOnly 
                    );

                if (lMatch)
                {
                    if (lSearchKeyOnly)
                    {
                        lDisplayPath = true;
                        lDisplayValue = false;
                    }
                    show(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lRegValueData, lDisplayPath, lDisplayValue, false);
                    lDisplayPath = false;
                    lDisplayValue = true;

                    lMatchTotal++;
                    lNewLine = true;
                }       
            }
            else
            {
                show(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lRegValueData, lDisplayPath, lDisplayValue, false);
                lDisplayPath = false;
            }
        }

        if (lSearchRecursive && !(lFilterDataType || lFind))
        {
            lNewLine = true;
        }

        if (lNewLine)
        {
            fwprintf(stdout, L"\n");
            lNewLine = false;
        }

        // Remove visted Sub-Key from deque 
        lCurrentSubKey = lSubKeyList.front();
        lSubKeyList.pop_front();

        if (lSearchRecursive && lCurrentSubKey != L"End")
        {
            // If the parent key contains sub-keys, add them to lSubKeyList, 
            // in the order they were retrieved from RegEnumEx.
            std::deque<std::wstring> lTemp;
            lResult = getSubKeyList(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lTemp);

            while (lTemp.size())
            {
                lSubKeyList.push_front(lTemp.back());
                lTemp.pop_back();
            }

            // A non-error. Error: "Invalid Handle"
            // This error code just states that the current key being accessed 
            // does not contain any sub-keys.
            if (lResult == 6) lResult = 0;

            if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                error(lResult);
                return false;
            }

            // Get the current keys value names
            if (!lSearchKeyOnly)
            {
                lResult = getValueNameList(hkey, lHkeyPath, lCurrentSubKey, lValueList);

                // Ignore key values that cannot be accessed. Error "Access Denied" 
                // Keys cannot be accessed in regedit (admin), so this is a UAC issue.
                if (lResult == 5) lResult = 0;

                if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    error(lResult);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #if defined (__writeToDisk)
    file.close();
    #endif

    if (lFind || lFilterDataType)
    {
        std::cout << "End of search : " << lMatchTotal << " match(es) found." << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful for reviewers if you added the missing header files (and possibly cpp files) to the question. Currently, it's hard to evaluate, since important information are missing.

Comment: What exactly is REG/your program doing?

Comment: @yuri Essentially, this program queries(searches) through the registry keys.  I have been following/implementing the features contained within this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query

Comment: @hoffmale I've added in the missing header files. Hopefully, I will be a bit easier to evaluate now.